# Давайте исправим ошибки в справке

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, статус-завершено

Этот вопрос уже [поднимался](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4129/) в мете ru.StaskOverflow. Оказывается, здесь есть аналогичные ошибки в [справке](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), а именно:

1) слово "бескорыстно" в разделе "Как написать хороший ответ?" написано с ошибкой ("безкорыстно");

2) написано "о всех" в разделе "Ответ на вопрос";

3) знаки пунктуации желательно отредактировать как описано [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/428525/184482).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ниже представлен текущий вариант справки. Пожалуйста, внесите необходимые правки и я обновлю страничку.

---

Мы благодарны вам за то, что вы потратили свое ценное время на написание ответа. Только благодаря таким людям, как вы, готовым бескорыстно помогать другим, мы вместе можем учиться новому.

#### Благодарите за ответы на ваши вопросы

Ваше простое искреннее «спасибо» очень ценно, но это не все, чем вы можете отблагодарить ответившего: проголосуйте за ответы, которые вам больше всего помогли, и, по возможности, отвечайте на вопросы других пользователей.

#### У вас такая же проблема?

Вы нашли на сайте вопрос, который интересен вам не менее, чем автору, но на него никто не ответил? Помогите найти решение, изучите проблему, поделитесь в ответе результатами своих исследований. Таким образом, даже если окончательное решение не будет найдено, тому, кто займется этим вопросом после вас, будет предоставлено больше полезной информации. Чтобы привлечь внимание к интересующему вас вопросу, вы можете проголосовать за него или [назначить вознаграждение](/help/bounty) за его решение.

#### Ответ на вопрос

Внимательно прочитайте вопрос, уясните, в чем заключается его суть. Перед написанием ответа подумайте, чем он будет полезен. Не стоит отвечать просто «не делай этого», следует добавить «попробуй вместо этого сделать следующее» – предложите достойную альтернативу. Любой ответ, который направляет спрашивающего в нужное русло, является ценным. Постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. Изложите свои предложения. Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше.

#### Оставляйте описание к ссылкам

Ссылки на внешние ресурсы – это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе с ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.

#### Пишите как можно лучше

Мы не ожидаем, что все ответы будут идеальны, но ответы с правильной орфографией, грамматикой и пунктуацией лучше воспринимаются. Кроме того, за них чаще голосуют. Помните, что вы можете в любое время вернуться и отредактировать ответ, чтобы его улучшить.

#### Отвечайте на [хорошо заданные](/help/how-to-ask) вопросы

Не на все вопросы стоит отвечать. Уберегите себя от разочарования и не отвечайте на вопросы, которые:

- непонятны или не содержат конкретных подробностей, что не позволяет однозначно определить проблему;
- провоцируют обмен [мнениями](/help/dont-ask), а не фактами;
- [уже задавались](/search) и получили не один ответ;
- требуют слишком много наводящей информации для полного ответа;
- требуют ответов на несколько вопросов сразу;
- не относятся к русскому языку, согласно определению в [Справке](/help/on-topic).

Не забывайте, что вы можете [отредактировать](/help/editing) вопрос, на который отвечаете, чтобы сделать его ясным и целенаправленным – это поможет избежать его [закрытия](/help/closed-questions) или [удаления](/help/deleted-questions).

#### Всегда будьте вежливы и доброжелательны

Вы можете выражать своё несогласие или сомнение, но [не забывайте о вежливости](/help/behavior), ведь с вами общаются реальные люди, которые тоже имеют право на ошибку. Мы здесь не для того, чтобы ссориться, а чтобы учиться друг у друга.

Comment: я внесла небольшие исправления, можно менять. Появился ещё небольшой вопрос не по теме - вы получаете тревоги с этого сайта? Я 12 декабря отмечала свой ответ тревогой с сообщением, что нужно участие модератора в этом вопросе.

Comment: @Mae Все тревоги отображаются лишь в интерфейсе конкретного сайта (то есть если я не зашел на Мету, я не увижу тревогу). Упоминания отображаются без привязки к сайту.

Comment: @Mae Большое спасибо! Обновил страницу справки!

Answer (score 0):

Если здесь нет модератора, обладающего возможностью и желанием править справку, я предлагаю дать мне на время (на сутки, например) полномочия и я сама исправлю.